# Prove that the function is surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let A={$3m-1|m\in Z$} and B={$4m+2|m\in Z$} and let $f:A\rightarrow B$ is defined by

$f(x)=\frac{4(x+1)}{3}-2$ . Is f surjective?

I'm not really sure how to prove this. By trying out certain values it seems it's surjective. This is my work so far:

$f(x)=y \iff \frac{4(x+1)}{3}-2 = y \iff x=\frac{3y+2}{4}$

If we substitute $y=4m+2$ then $x=\frac{3(4m+2)+2}{4} \iff x=\frac{12m+8}{4} \iff x=3m+2$. Although this is not exactly $ A = 3m-1$ it seems that no matter which number for m you choose you basically get the same set in the end.

Same if we do $f(A)=B \iff f(3m-1)=4m+2 \iff \frac{4(3m-1+1)}{3}-2=4m+2 \iff $

$\iff 4m-2=4m+2$. Obviously these two are not equal yet they yield the same exact sets since they are infinite. So is f surjective? It seems like it , but these two proofs are not exactly very precise.

Answer (score 3):

Just see that

$$3m+2=3(m+1)-1=3M-1$$

and $M\in \Bbb Z$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $x=3m+2 \implies x=3(m+1)-1$.

Comment: Didn't actually know I can rewrite that. Thanks

Comment: @DreaDk no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Solve $f(3n-1) = 4m+2$ to get $n=m+1$.

In particular, for any $b \in B$ there is some $a \in A$ such that
$f(a) = b$.

In fact, it is unique.

In particular, it is not hard to compute $f^{-1}(b) = {1 \over 2} b$.